# How do I give an id to an appended element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The one I'm talking about is one where I have the code appear literally, a string. How do I combine it with actual code, like `<div id="thing">string goes here</div>`?
I've tried making the div and id part of the content inside the `(' ')` but it doesn't work. When I do that, the content never gets appended.

Here's the code:

```
$('#placeToAppendTo').append
('&lt;br&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;input&nbsp;type="text"&nbsp;class="textfield"&nbsp;id="text'+textClicked+'"&lt;/div&gt;');
```

Comment: Show your code please.., Not a clue on what you are talking about.

Comment: Can you show your code or clarify your question?

Comment: @user2255654 I have provided a possible solution

Answer (score 4):

To get the HTML you presented, you would do something like this:

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.id = "thing";
elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode("string goes here"));
```

I hope this helps, since your question isn't particularly clear.

Comment: +1 for the use of vanillaJS and creteTextNode instead of the commonly used innerText :)

Answer (score 1):

or in jQuery:

```
$('<div />', {id:'thing', text:'string goes here'});
```